# how to calculate the loss event rate p in TFRC(tcp friendly rate control) when no packet loss?

Tags: networking, congestion-control

When there is packet loss , I know the method to calculate the p (I read in the RFC document).

But when there is no packet loss , how to calculate it?  The document show nothing about it.

**If the loss event rate p is zero, the denominator of equation in tfrc is 0.**

The equation is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHsu7.png)

and the document is rfc5348 : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5348

Comment: Add more details to your question.

Comment: hi , I add the equation and the documents address.

Comment: How to calculate the loss rate when there is no loss? The equation you cite is for TCP, not TFRC. Your question doesn't make sense. It is also off topic.

Comment: hi @EJP , the TFRC use the TCP equation.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about TFRC so pure guesswork here.

I suppose available bandwidth calculation is based on loss event rate. If no packets were lost up to now you have zero info about available bandwidth. Usually in this case Congestion Avoidance algo increases bitrate until packet drops start to occur.

In other words, if no packet drops so far you can assume your available bandwidth is unlimited, and use max possible value of `p`'s type. This exactly follows from the formula, as division by zero gives you infinity in math.